# How create your own ASP.NET MVC scaffolding template for views?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, templates, razor, view, scaffolding

How create and use your own ASP.NET MVC scaffolding template?
In "add Controller" wizard there is an "template" option with Microsoft templates. I would like to add new ones. A customized one. is that possible?

[image]

edit

In Visual Studio 2015 there is no template option anymore.

[image]

Comment: [How to Create Custom Scaffold Templates in ASP.NET MVC](https://www.credera.com/blog/technology-insights/microsoft-solutions/create-custom-scaffold-templates-asp-net-mvc/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify the T4 templates used by Visual Studio. This is a good article on how to do it:

https://www.credera.com/blog/technology-insights/microsoft-solutions/create-custom-scaffold-templates-asp-net-mvc/

You copy the default templates into your project "CodeTemplates" folder. You can then alter the templates without affecting the defaults.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)